# Do MySQL Triggers Activate Other Triggers?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, relational-database, relationship

For example, if I defined a trigger that deleted all comments for a post when that post is deleted. Would a trigger that deletes all posts when a user is deleted activate the other trigger thus removing the comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is **Yes.**

Demo:

```
mysql> create table users (id serial primary key);

mysql> create table posts (id serial primary key, userid bigint unsigned);

mysql> create table comments (id serial primary key, postid bigint unsigned);

mysql> create trigger udel after delete on users for each row delete from posts where userid = OLD.id;

mysql> create trigger pdel after delete on posts for each row delete from comments where postid = OLD.id;

mysql> insert into users values (123);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into posts values (456, 123);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into comments values (789, 456);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 123 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from posts;
+-----+--------+
| id  | userid |
+-----+--------+
| 456 |    123 |
+-----+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from comments;
+-----+--------+
| id  | postid |
+-----+--------+
| 789 |    456 |
+-----+--------+
```

Now we try to delete, which should cascade to the other tables:

```
mysql> delete from users;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select * from posts;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from comments;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```